# How to scale elasticsearch that it can index a large number of documents per second?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a basic elasticsearch cluster at the moment in which I am using a river to index data. I want to scale for future growth in two phases. Number of documents indexed per second is what could be the bottleneck.

1. Phase 1: Indexing 100 documents per second into elasticsearch
2. Phase 2: Indexing 10000 documents per second into elasticsearch

How should I go about it?

Thanks-in-advance!

Edit:
I am trying to index the Twitter stream.
Each document = around 2 KB.
Hardware is flexible. Right now I have magnetic disks (with 50 GB RAM) but getting SSD (and better config) is no biggie.

Comment: I'll use the bulk api for that purpose but if you don't give us more information about your data size or specificity of your hardware and what you are trying to achieve, we will not be able to help you!

Comment: @eliasah thanks. I've edited my answer with the details...

Comment: are you using Logstash, a river or another solution?

Comment: yes, I am using the elasticsearch twitter river at the moment. But if it cant keep up in the future, I am fine with writing my own code to stream and index the tweets...

Comment: You also have logstash as alternative solution which is good. How about your river settings, and more specifically the bulk_size parameter? and how much resource did you give for elasticsearch? how much RAM?

Comment: Whats the additional benefit of using Logstash? I just don't understand it's use case for something like tweets, in fact anything outside the logs use case. I read about it and seems like it reads input from Redis, but if I have to setup Redis, I might as well just use the Redis river to directly index into ES!

Comment: First, rivers are deprecated and they will be removed in further versions. Second, Logstash is more flexible than rivers. Ex: you might want to perform an extra preprocessing on the input. The rivers don't allow that unlike Logstash.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks! So, like you mentioned Logstash can do pre-processing. I assume it won't be distributed i.e. doing large calculations on data to add a new field would run on the same machine and probably slow down the entire thing?

Comment: Large computing or distributed? That's two different things. Logstash can be distributed but I'm not sure it can handle large computing algorithms.

Comment: I meant distributing to parallelize big calculations on data. So, you mean I can setup a Logstash cluster to utilize the Twitter input, then do some calculations and send to ES cluster? In this case would all Logstash nodes fetch and process the data?

Comment: Some how yes! The terminology you are using is not quite accurate thought. But you can consider your Logstash "nodes" as rivers. And "big calculations" on data cannot be handled in both streaming processes (river or Logstash). You are not trying to apply classification algorithms upon tweets stream I suppose. So I think that Logstash can do the job for you!

Answer (score 1):

A few highlights that come from experiments and articles:

- Since you will do a lot of writing, make sure you start with a good number of primary shards. You can make that decision based on the number of nodes you will have/need. Basically, you want to make sure that your primary shards are distributed on different nodes so they can share the work. You can't change the number of primary shards once your index is created, so think it out.
- Do not assign more than 50% of your machine's memory to ES. The rest will be used by Lucene (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html)
- Use a SSD. When indexing, I/O plays a big role (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing/)
- Generally: I/O > Memory > Multiple CPU Cores > Fast single CPU (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html)
- Pretty much each setup is unique, so the best way to find out what the optimal configurations are for you is to try it out. Elasticsearch has a great monitoring tool called Marvel (http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/)

Have fun !